# Why Does Yesod Require PathPiece for Hidden Fields

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

The type signature for creating hidden fields in Yesod is: `hiddenField :: (Monad m, PathPiece p, RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) => Field m p`. This is the only field which requires the `PathPiece` constraint, why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hiddenField` is a very free-form field, unlike e.g. `textField` which specifically works on `Text`. `hiddenField` will work on any type which can be marshalled to and from a textual representation, which is where the `PathPiece` constraint comes into play.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! If I may, why `PathPiece` rather than a `Show` and `Read` constraint?

Comment: Although Show and Read are commonly inverses of each other, there's no requirement that that be the case, whereas such a requirement does exist for PathPiece's toPathPiece and fromPathPiece. Additionally, PathPiece avoids dropping down to String, since it works on Text values. But if I was to do it again today, I might go with ToJSON/FromJSON instead.